# How to display different navigation for different language in XenForo 2?

Tags: php, conditional-statements, expression, xenforo

I want to show personalized menu for different languages in XenForo 2.

I did not find any clue how to do that, except it has this option to display navigation item in condition. (see image)

What must be the conditional expression for example if i want to display an item only when the language is in english?

I tried this, but it did not work:

```
{$xf.visitorLanguage.language_code} == 'en'
```

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EElSa.jpg)

Comment: anyone know how?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use "en-US" not "en"